# Как узнать все подэлементы объекта?

Tags: ооп, javascript

Есть какой-нибудь объект, например `example`. Мне надо узнать все его подобъекты (например `example.x` или `example.y.z`). Как это сделать?

Comment: Google в помощь: http://blog.sribna.com/kak-poluchit-vse-svoystva-obekta-v-javascript.htm

Comment: Можно как нибудь поподробней и в виде функции: allobgect(obgect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В объекте 2 подобъекта, они показаны:

```
var obj = {                    _
    'nestedObj': {          _   |
        'nestedObj': {       |  |
            'prop': 'value'  |  |
        },                  _|  |
        'prop': 'value'         |
    },                         _|
    'prop': 'value',
    'func': function(){},
    'array': []
}
```

Функция, которая их выявит:

```
var getNestedObjects = function getNestedObjects(object){
    var result = [];
    for(var prop in object){
        var value = object[prop];
        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(value) == '[object Object]'){ // является ли свойство объектом
            result.push(value)
            result = result.concat(getNestedObjects(value));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(getNestedObjects(obj)); // [{nestedObj : {prop: value }, prop: value}, {prop: value}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть [for...in](http://javascript.ru/for..in):

> Перебрать свойства объекта, для каждого свойства выполнить заданный код.

Answer (score 2):

```
obj = {a:"aaa", b:"bbb", c:{d:"ddd", e:"eee"}}

...

for (o in obj) {
    if(typeof o === 'object') {
        // рекурсия
    }
    console.log(o);
}

...
```

Comment: не самый удачный пример:

    var str = new String('dwa');
    typeof str === 'object' // true

Comment: Ага, но идея ясна) Спасибо за замечание.